# Scrolling/zooming a scene in OpenGL and subdivision

Tags: android, opengl-es, scroll, zooming

We are to develop a scrolling/zooming scene in OpenGL ES on Android, very much like a level in Angry Birds but more like a level in World Of Goo. More like the latter as the world will not consist of repeated layers as featured in Angry Birds but of a large image. As the scene needs to scroll/zoom and therefore a lot of it will not be visible, I was wondering about the most efficient way to implement the rendering, focusing on the environment only (ie not the objects within the world but background layers).

We will be using an orthographic projection.

The first that comes to mind is creating a large 4 vertices rectangle at world size, which has the background texture mapped to it, and translate/scale this using glTranslatef / glScalef. However, I was wondering if the non visible area outside of the screens boundaries is still being rendered by OpenGL as it is not being culled (you would lose the visible area as well as there are only 4 vertices). Therefore, would it be more efficient to subdivide this rectangle, so non visible smaller rectangles can be culled?

Another option would be creating a 4 vertice rectangle that would fill the screen, then move the background by adjusting its texture coordinates. However, I guess we would run into problems when building bigger worlds, considering the texture size limit. It seems like a nice implementation for repeated backgrounds like AngryBirds has.

Maybe there is another way..?

If someone has an idea on how it might be done in AngryBirds / World of Goo, please share as I'd love to hear. They seem to have implemented a system that allows for the world to be moved and zoomed very (WorldOfGoo = VERY) smoothly.

Comment: I actually think that the purpose of culling is to send less vertices to into the graphics pipeline. If you subdivide the rectangle too much, you will be sending more vertices. In general, the GPU should know well to clip prmitives - it's part of the processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably your best bet for [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217822/large-scrolling-background-in-opengl-es).

In my experience, keeping a large texture in memory is very expensive on Android. I would get quite a few OutOfMemoryError exceptions for the background texture before I moved to tiling.

I think the biggest rendering bottleneck would be with memory transfer speeds and fill rate instead of any graphics computation.

**Edit:** Check out 53:28 of this [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic#t=53m28s) from Google I/O 2009.

Comment: Are you sure about that? E.g. the second paragraph of 10.040 of the OpenGL FAQ (http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/clipping.htm) opens with "When a primitive lies partially outside the window, it often crosses the view volume boundary. OpenGL must clip any primitive that crosses the view volume boundary. "

Comment: Not sure, now you bring it up. I never relied on OpenGL to do any clipping. I'll make an edit.

Comment: But that would mean a lot of texture binding. Those are one of the most expensive operations in OpenGL right?

Comment: More expensive than waiting for the screen to fill? I don't see anyway around it.

Comment: which OpenGL Version are you going to use for your game? This question could be very important for the solution of your problem.

Comment: If that is the case I would like to know about both ways as thats not sure yet

Answer (score 0):

You could split the background rectangle into smaller rectangles, so that OpenGL only renders the visible rectangles. You won't have a big ass rectangle with a big ass texture loaded but smallers rectangles with smaller textures that you could load/unload, depending on what is visible on screen...

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there would be no performance drop due to large areas being rendered off-screen, subdividing and culling is normally done just to reduce vertex count, but you would actually be adding to it here.

Putting that aside for now; from the way you phrased the question I am unsure whether you have a large background texture or a small repeating one. If it is large, then you will need to subdivide because of texture size limitations anyway, so the question is moot! If it is small, then I would suggest the second method, fit a quad to the screen and move the background by changing the texture coordinates.

I feel like I may have missed something, though, as I am unsure why you mentioned the texture size limitation issue when talking about the the texture coordinate method and not the large quad method. Surely for both this is not a problem for repeating textures as you can use GL_REPEAT texture wrap mode...

But for both it *is* a problem for a single large texture unless you subdivide, which would make the texture coordinate tactic way more complicated than necessary. In this case subdividing the mesh along texture subdivisions would be best, and culling off-screen sections. Deciding which parts to cull should be trivial with this technique.

Cheers.